# SQL query to get the correct results

Tags: sql

I am having issue trying to get the below select work.
Can anyone help?
Thanks.

```
SELECT 
        i.InventoryID,i.AttributeSKUID,s.AttributeValue
    FROM 
        ma_product_inventory i
    LEFT JOIN
        ma_product_attribute_sku s
    ON
        i.AttributeSKUID=s.AttributeSKUID
    LEFT JOIN
        ma_product p
    ON
        p.ProductID=s.ProductID
    WHERE 
        s.ProductID='1'
    AND
        (
        s.AttributeValue='xs'
        OR
        s.AttributeValue='green'
        )
```

I am getting the below results:

```
INVENTORYID ATTRIBUTESKUID  ATTRIBUTEVALUE
1   1   xs
1   1   green
2   2   green
3   3   green
4   4   green
5   5   green
6   6   xs
```

How can i get the AttributeSKUID?

Thanks.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387ee/34 look..works perfectly

Comment: I need to get the same AttributeSKUID based on selected color and size. If I change the color and size, then the AttributeSKUID should be something like 2 for both results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select s.AttributeSKUID 
from
ma_product_attribute_sku s
LEFT JOIN
ma_product p
ON
p.ProductID=s.ProductID
WHERE 
s.ProductID='1'
AND
(s.AttributeValue='xl'
OR
s.AttributeValue='red')
Group by 
S.AttributeSKUID
having count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the end of your query
`GROUP BY s.AttributeValue`

Answer (score 2):

try using `SELECT DISTINCT` and why did you join to **ma_product p**? It seems you didn't use that table.

Comment: I intend to use it later for the price once I sort this out. :)

Comment: I tried: Distinct i.InventoryID, i.AttributeSKUID, s.AttributeValue... But it doesn't work... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387ee/59 ... I like to return only if there is two identical AttributeSKUID

Comment: try modifying your where into this `WHERE s.attributeskuid='2'`

Comment: Thanks, but actually the select statement purpose is to get the AttributeSKUID, therefore the AttributeSKUID is unknown until I provide the ProductID, Color and Size.

Answer (score 2):

try adding distinct at kyusan93 code `Select distinct(s.attribute),i.inventoryId,s.attributevalue` group by S.attributeSKUID having count (*) =2 - this will get all attributeSKUID repeated twice. Hope that will help you.